# Finding root of symbolic function

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I'm trying to find a root of the following equation
$$\theta^\frac{t}{s}-\theta-\sqrt{1-p},$$
where $0<t\leq1\leq s$ and $0<p<1$. 
I've tried FindRoot and Reduce, but somehow they don't process the output.

Using reduce function, what I tried is

```
Reduce[theta^(t/s) - theta - Sqrt[1 - p] == 0 && theta > 0 && theta < 1 &&0 < t<=  1<=s && 0 < p < 1, theta]
```

Any suggestions on how to solve for a symbolic function?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139881/mathematica-wont-solve-h-tx-ltx-xc-p

Comment: @MichaelE2 has given you the answer.  Probably the best you can do is solve explicitly for the exponent:  $\frac{r}{s}\to \frac{\log \left(\theta +\sqrt{1-p}\right)}{\log (\theta )}$.

Comment: What is the unknown?

Comment: $\theta$ is the unknown and I want to find roots (probably there will be two of them) of the above equation. All the rest is just parameters. I've tried by simplifuying the equation into $\theta^a-\theta-b$, where $a=\frac{t}{s}$ and $b=\sqrt{1-p}$, but still just don't know how to solve for roots...

Comment: This is not the type of equations for which I would expect symbolic solutions.Try numerics.

Comment: All right, thanks for the comments.

Comment: Since `a` is any real this problem has no exact solution. One can go for a numeric one, or, as MichaelE2 offered plot it parametrically, or make a table of values parametrically. There is also an analytical possibility. If `b` is small, there is a method referred to as a "Newton's diagram" to build all asymptotically exact solutions of such equations. Description one finds in the first chapter of the book: M. M. Vainberg and V. A. Trenogin, Theory of branching of solutions of non-linear equations. (Noordhoff International, Leyden, 1974).

Answer (score -1):

The t/s is somehow a nasty in this question. The inequality chain make t/s limited by 0 and 1. 1 means t==s. At this point the equation reduces to Sqrt[1-p] and is satisfied only for p==1.

Following this path replace u=t/s and solve the equation.

```
p[theta_, u_] := 1 - (theta^u - theta)^2

Plot3D[p[theta, u], {theta, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]
[image]

The quotient t/s makes the equation unnecessary complicated. u makes it trivial.

It is too meaningful to replace the Sqrt[1-p] by q for example and

```
Plot3D[theta^u - theta, {u, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Plot3D]

For very large s the quotient t/s->0 and the equation gets

```
1-theta-Sqrt[1-p]

Reduce[1 - theta - Sqrt[1 - p] == 0, {p, theta}]
```

(* theta == 1 - Sqrt[1 - p] *)

```
Plot3D[theta == 1 - Sqrt[1 - p], {p, 0, 1}, {theta, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot3D]

```
Reduce[theta^u - theta - Sqrt[1 - p] == 0 && theta > 0 && theta < 1 &&
   0 < p < 1, u]
(* Element[C[1], Integers] && 0 < p < 1 && 0 < theta < 1 && 
  u == (2*I*Pi*C[1] + Log[Sqrt[1 - p] + theta])/Log[theta] *)

Plot3D[Log[Sqrt[1 - p] + theta]/Log[theta], {p, 0, .95}, {theta, 0, .9}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Plot3D]

This is not so informativ and comfortable to look at if p->1 and theta->1.